# Html to FOP with XSLT: css class to attribute-set

Tags: html, css, xslt, apache-fop

I use a small html document to create a pdf.

- I want to use the html attribute **class** for the fo styles.
- I define some **attribute-set**s

My Html Snippet:

```
<body>
<p class="small justify">
   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor ...
</p>
</body>
```

My XSLT Snippet:

```
<xsl:attribute-set="small">
    <xsl:attribute name="font-size">10pt</xsl:attribute>
</xsl:attribute-set>
<xsl:attribute-set="justify">
    <xsl:attribute name="text-align">justify</xsl:attribute>
</xsl:attribute-set>

<!-- Is okay -->
<xsl:template match="p">
   <fo:block xsl:use-attribute-sets="small test">
       <xsl:apply-templates/>
   </fo:blick>
</xsl:template>

<!-- BUT Is NOT okay -->
<xsl:template match="p">
   <fo:block xsl:use-attribute-sets="@class">
       <xsl:apply-templates/>
   </fo:blick>
</xsl:template>
```

How can I transfer the value from **class** to the **use-attribute-sets**?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> How can I transfer the value from class to the use-attribute-sets?

Unfortunately, **you cannot**.

According to the XSL recommendation ([1.0](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#attribute-sets), [2.0](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#attribute-sets) and [3.0](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#attribute-sets)), the value of `xsl:use-attribute-sets` is **a whitespace-separated list of names of attribute sets**, so it cannot be an expression, not even one producing a whitespace-separated list of names.

(Not that it matters but note that, if what you want were possible, you would have to use curly brackets around your expression: `xsl:use-attribute-sets="{@class}"`. )